# Parse JSON date

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I am using Grails as server and ExtJS as client. Now I need to update a date field of domain with specific date value from JSON. But when I want to update with specific date the error is like this

> Cannot cast object 'dd MM, yyyy' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'

Now how can I update the specific date from JSON into database? Here is my server update action:

```
def update(json) {
    def count = 0
    def flag = true
    def installments = []
    def pdate = json.payDate
    def payDate = pdate.format("dd MM, yyyy")
    def newCashPay = Double.parseDouble("${json.cashPay}")
    def newReturnAmount = Double.parseDouble("${json.returnAmount}")
    if(json instanceof JSONObject){            
        def c = Installment.get(Integer.parseInt("${json.id}"))
        if(c){   
            c.activeFlag = true
            c.cashPay = newCashPay
            c.returnAmount = newReturnAmount
            c.payDate = payDate
            if(c.validate()){
                c.save()
            }else{                        
                c.errors.each {
                    println it
                }
            }
        }

        def installment = [id:c.id, accNo:c.accNo, memberNo:c.memberNo, branchId:c.branchId, installmentNo:c.installmentNo, weekStart:c.weekStart, weekEnd:c.weekEnd, payDate:c.payDate, payAmount:c.payAmount, lateFee:c.lateFee, cashPay:c.cashPay, returnAmount:c.returnAmount, activeFlag:c.activeFlag]
        installments << installment
        flag = flag && true
        count++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
def payDate = pdate.format("dd MM, yyyy")
```

Don't you mean

```
def payDate = Date.parse( "dd MM, yyyy", pdate )
```